# Impresiones C# Quiero crear una excepción para cuando la impresora no no pueda imprimir por cualquier motivo

Tags: c#, print, imprimir

Estoy utilizando la librería de **'System.Drawing.Printing'**
Tengo un Windows Form con los datos de compras. Estoy pasándole los datos a la impresora e imprime bien.
Pero *quiero que* me notifique si hay problemas con la impresión.
No sé donde agregarlo ni tampoco como hacerlo.

**Mi idea es** hacer una función nueva que pregunte a la impresora si tiene papel suficiente, y si es así que llame la función de imprimir; sino que envíe un MessageBox que avise que "hubo problemas en la impresión".

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.